# Uncaught TypeError: c(...).tScrollable is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

> Uncaught TypeError: c(...).tScrollable is not a function in telerik.grid.min.js

When the application is browsed from visual studio 2012 it is getting browsed properly. But when it is published and hosted in local IIS, the browser console is throwing the following error.

Comment: Have you missed any js files while publishing? verify the files and path.. publish the solution manually and try

Comment: @NijinKoderi I tried publishing the project manually even but it did not stop the problem. When I am browsing it directly from visual studio, it is running fine but when hosted in IIS, this problem is occurring

Comment: Can you confirm if all required libraries are being imported in IIS?

Comment: @iamdlm Actually I have published the project and in the published folder I can see all the required files but it is not able to read the code somehow

Comment: So if you open your browser developer tools "Network" tab, do you see the required libraries being loaded?